# How to fix android:debugable error?

Tags: android

while setting the debugable option true in android

```
android:debugable="true"
```

i am facing the following error,

> Avoid hardcoding the debug mode; leaving it out allows debug and release builds to automatically assign one

can anybody please tell me how can i fix this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to write this code in your manifest. just **Remove** this `android:debugable="true"` code from  manifest.

According to sdk guide line:

Support for a true debug build. Developers no longer need to add the  `android:debuggable` attribute to the  `<application>` tag in the manifest — the build tools add the attribute automatically. In Eclipse/ADT, all incremental builds are assumed to be debug builds, so the tools insert  `android:debuggable="true"`. When exporting a signed release build, the tools do not add the attribute. In Ant, a ant debug command automatically inserts the android:debuggable="true" attribute, while ant release does not. If `android:debuggable="true"` is manually set, then ant release will actually do a debug build, rather than a release build.